# Why am I not getting files after injecting an environment variable?

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables

**Shell Script**

```
git clonerepo project_name project
cd project
git checkout master
git fetch "https://sam@gerrit.com:443/a/project_name" refs/changes/56/157656/1 && git cherry-pick 
FETCH_HEAD
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git fetch --tags'
git submodule update --init --recursive

**#I am getting the modified files in the review here, let modified files='abc.txt cd.txt'.The modified 
files are space-separated.**
modified_files=$(git diff HEAD..origin/$GERRIT_BRANCH --name-only)
cd ../
echo $modified_files
```

*output:*
*abc.txt cd.txt*

**#injecting a new env variable MODIFIED_FILES here**

```
echo "MODIFIED_FILES=$modified_files" > $BUILD_NUMBER"_modified_files.txt"
```

**after injecting env variable I am using this variable in python script. but there  I am getting only one file "abc.txt"**

**Python script**

```
import os
modified_files = os.environ.get('MODIFIED_FILES')
print(modified_files)
```

*output:
abc.txt*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in Python, but in your shell command line.

```sh
$ echo "MODIFIED_FILES=$modified_files"
MODIFIED_FILES=abc.txt cd.txt
```

Do you see the issue? Only the first file name will be in that variable. This is why you should always double quote variables.

Suggestion no. 2: If you want environment variable, you should export it.

Suggestion no. 3: Double quote the entire file name and wrap the variable name with curly braces.

```sh
echo "export MODIFIED_FILES=\"$modified_files\"" > "${BUILD_NUMBER}_modified_files.txt"
```

Comment: echo "export MODIFIED_FILES=\"$modified_files\"" > "${BUILD_NUMBER}_modified_files.txt" is returning none

Comment: I used echo "MODIFIED_FILES=\"$modified_files\"" > "${BUILD_NUMBER}_modified_files.txt" and it returned " abc.txt and not the second file.

Comment: and echo "MODIFIED_FILES=$modified_files" returns 
MODIFIED_FILES=abc.txt\n
cd.txt

Comment: If you have line break, in the $modified_files, they should be removed.
echo "MODIFIED_FILES=\"$(tr -d '\n' <<< $modified_files)\"" > "${BUILD_NUMBER}_modified_files.txt"
Does this help?